# change a partitioned table schema in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table in big query and I wanted to change the schema of that table. 
I have changed the schema of table before using the following sql from the web UI

```
'SELECT * REPLACE ((SELECT AS STRUCT whatever.* EXCEPT (columnName)) AS whatever) FROM `a:b.c`'
```

but this causes all the previous partitions to be lost and when I look for the partitions of this newly created table using the following command it gives me today's date

```
SELECT _PARTITIONTIME as pt, FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", _PARTITIONTIME) as partition_id
FROM `a.b.c`
GROUP BY _PARTITIONTIME
ORDER BY _PARTITIONTIME
```

Is it possible to change the schema of a table and also keep its partitions in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is stated in the documentation ( [link 1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#manually_adding_an_empty_column), [link 2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas)) all the possible modifications that are available and changing a partitioned table to a non-partitioned table is not listed. However, there is a work around.

In order to change a Partitioned table to a Non-partitioned table, you can use the Console to query your data and overwrite your current table or copy to a new one. As an example, I have a table in BigQuery partitioned by ***_PARTITIONTIME***. I used the following query to create a non-partitioned table,

```
SELECT *, _PARTITIONTIME as pt FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

With the above code, you will query the data among all table's partitions and create an extra column to show which partition it came from. Then, before executing it, there are two options, save the view in a new non-partitioned table or overwrite the current table:

1. Creating a new table go to: *More(under the query editor)* > *Query Settings* > *Check the box* "**Set a destination table for query results**" > *Choose your project, dataset and write your new table's name* > *Under* **Destination table write preference** *check* **Write if empty**.
2. Overwriting the current table: *More(under the query editor)* > *Query Settings* > *Check the box* "**Set a destination table for query results**" > *Choose the same project and dataset for your current table* > *Write the same table's name as the one you want to overwrite* > *Under* **Destination table write preference** *check* **Overwrite table**.